# pgAdmin4 not working - How to solve not listening 5432 on postgresql after set config file correctly

Tags: networking, postgresql, pgadmin

I am a novice ubuntu user. I am working on an ubuntu 18.04 VM on Windows10 machine through Putty. I installed postgreql & I am trying to install pgadmin4 but it's not working.

When I run the pgadmin4.py, 127.0.0.1:5050 doesn't open in the browser. It says `'Unable to connect'`

Opening it in curl on command line raises error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5050: Connection refused
```

While trying to run psql, the server doesn't start.

```
root@pan0138:/# sudo -i -u postgres
postgres@pan0138:~$ psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I tried to make configuration files postgresql & pg_hba correct following the similar threads but it doesn't work.

Here are links to my configuration files:

Postgresql.conf

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Aji6qteTxOtX63ITXyXQaeEi3rnA-kDh/view

pg_hba.conf

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X9PN2KRL4EtwOeewJqHlu171HUF_w8O9/view

Here is the output of the `# ss -nlt`:

```
root@pan0138:/# ss -nlt
State          Recv-Q          Send-Q                    Local Address:Port                   Peer Address:Port
LISTEN         0               128                       127.0.0.53%lo:53                          0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN         0               128                             0.0.0.0:22                          0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN         0               5                             127.0.0.1:631                         0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN         0               128                           127.0.0.1:6010                        0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN         0               128                                   *:80                                *:*
LISTEN         0               128                                [::]:22                             [::]:*
LISTEN         0               5                                 [::1]:631                            [::]:*
LISTEN         0               128                               [::1]:6010                           [::]:*
```

Here is link to  pastebin link:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mRsdN6QJYy/

Seems something caused blocked 5432 port. How to solve this problem ?

**EDIT**

The problem of the 5432 not listening is solved. I simply remove --purge to remove installed version of the postgresql & install fresh copy by following 
[How to Install PostgreSQL on Ubuntu 18.04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-postgresql-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

```
root@pan0138:~# sudo netstat -lp | grep postgres
tcp        0      0 localhost:postgresql    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22928/postgres
tcp6       0      0 localhost:postgresql    [::]:*                  LISTEN      22928/postgres
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2510282  22928/postgres       /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
root@pan0138:~# sudo netstat -lp | grep 5432
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2510282  22928/postgres       /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     65432    651/gdm3
```

The configuration in pg_hba_conf I made like

```
local      all          postgres                        peer
local      all          all                             trust
host       all          all          0.0.0.0/0          trust
host       all          all          ::/0               trust
```

and re-run pgAdmin4.py but the page 127.0.0.1:5050 still not opening, 'Unable to connect'. curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5050: Connection refused.

Here is link to `systemctl -l status postgresql | pastebinit`

[Paste from root at Thu, 13 Sep 2018 08:44:40 +0000](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/S5zHWdxmyX/)

Comment: You have some invalid configuration item.  Please **do not** post error log data as screenshots and instead try and figure out what those actual errors are, and fix your configurations.

Comment: try to change `host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            trust` and `host    all             all             ::/0            trust`

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri: do I replace md5 with trust in pg_hba.conf ?

Comment: yes sir, and restart postgresql with type `sudo systemctl restart postgresql@10-main.service`

Comment: It doesn't start the server: Job for postgresql@10-main.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.

Comment: @ThomasWard: can you please help figure out & correct what are the invalid configurations

Comment: Nope, not without the rest of your configuration data which we can't see in your screenshot.  I would do `systemctl -l status posgtgresql | pastebinit` and share the pastebin link with us so we can see the full output.  (You will need to install `pastebinit` first - `sudo apt-get install pastebinit`)

Comment: I installed 'pastebinit' & run the command. It returns: root@pan0138:/# systemctl -l status posgtgresql | pastebinit
Unit posgtgresql.service could not be found.
You are trying to send an empty document, exiting.

Comment: use `systemctl -l status postgresql | pastebinit`

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mRsdN6QJYy/

Comment: why i cannot see where the default 5432 port postgres on your netstat?

Comment: These are link to configuration files postgresql1.conf & pg_hba1.conf. The port 5432 is configured in postgresql1.conf. I don't know why it's not available or blocked
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Aji6qteTxOtX63ITXyXQaeEi3rnA-kDh.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1X9PN2KRL4EtwOeewJqHlu171HUF_w8O9

Comment: try to type `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432`

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri: 
root@pan0138:/# psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: inside to `sudo -i -u postgres` first and type `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432`

Comment: postgres@pan0138:~$ psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?